# Syntax for changing text properties in a ListView

Tags: basic4android

I have about 25 entries in a ListView by using:

```
ListView1.AddTwoLinesAndBitmap2("Entry Title","Entry Description",Bitmap1,1)
```

I'm looking to change the text size and color of the Entry Title and Entry Description. I tried setting properties as if it were a single line but had no luck. I'm not sure how to reference the first line and second individually.

Comment: Solved this by using TwoLinesAndBitmap instead of TwoLinesAndBitmap2... does TwoLinesAndBitmap2 not allow for customization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using TwoLinesAndBitmap instead of TwoLinesAndBitmap2... does TwoLinesAndBitmap2

Answer (score 2):

To modify the title appearance you should change:

```
Dim lv As ListView
lv.TwoLinesAndBitmap.Label.TextSize = 15
```

It doesn't matter if you use AddTwoLinesAndBitmap or AddTwoLinesAndBitmap2.